# iOS 14.x and Cordova iOS Platform: Nothing appears any more except text

Tags: webview, host, ios14, cordova-ios

I have a problem similar with iOS 14. I tried with both the current version of Cordova 5.x.x and the new 6.1.1, no difference.

The application starts, but at the moment of the main screen no images are loaded nor anything else only the texts are displayed. The only thing that happens is that the screen flashes black and white intermittently.

I have an application that I built with RPG Maker MV and then through this guide https://rmmv.neocities.org/page/01_11_06.html I was able to successfully port it to iOS up to version 13.7. Now with iOS 14.0 I get errors which are the following:

```
Your application might be rejected by Apple if you store too much data.
For more information please read "iOS Data Storage Guidelines" at:
https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/
To disable web storage backup to iCloud, set the BackupWebStorage preference to "local" in the Cordova config.xml file
2020-09-18 16:22:23.338371+0200 The Stranger[19593:446006] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID xxxxxxxx> xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xx
2020-09-18 16:22:23.394385+0200 The Stranger[19593:446006] Using UIWebView
2020-09-18 16:22:23.396781+0200 The Stranger[19593:446006] [CDVTimer][console] 0.072956ms
2020-09-18 16:22:23.396997+0200 The Stranger[19593:446006] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.045896ms
2020-09-18 16:22:23.398448+0200 The Stranger[19593:446006] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 1.309037ms
2020-09-18 16:22:23.398624+0200 The Stranger[19593:446006] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.049114ms
2020-09-18 16:22:23.398722+0200 The Stranger[19593:446006] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 2.091050ms
2020-09-18 16:22:23.538489+0200 The Stranger[19593:446006] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2020-09-18 16:22:23.573205+0200 The Stranger[19593:446006] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.585137+0200 The Stranger[19593:446006] Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
2020-09-18 16:22:23.588609+0200 The Stranger[19593:446006] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2020-09-18 16:22:23.589595+0200 The Stranger[19593:446006] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.660452+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.679532+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.681172+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.682216+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.683464+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.686978+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.688237+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.691343+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.694673+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.696115+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.697808+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.699445+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.700956+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.702411+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.703976+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.705426+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.848544+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.879554+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.880738+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.882365+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.883548+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.884872+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.885891+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.886837+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.887747+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.888932+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.890503+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.891660+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.905683+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:23.907627+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:24.156071+0200 The Stranger[19593:446006] PixiJS 4.5.4 - WebGL - http://www.pixijs.com/
2020-09-18 16:22:24.247957+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:24.249164+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.279530+0200 The Stranger[19593:446506] [aurioc] AURemoteIO.h:323:entry: Unable to join I/O thread to workgroup ((null)): 2
2020-09-18 16:22:25.292225+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.329316+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.330246+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.331025+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.332093+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.333119+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.334072+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.335199+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.336358+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.337450+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.338725+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.339760+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.340666+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.342065+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.342886+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.345483+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.442733+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.444177+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.445941+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.447277+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.448583+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.450072+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.451115+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.452440+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.453772+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.455007+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.586546+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.587656+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.588704+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.589610+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:25.879039+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:26.431780+0200 The Stranger[19593:446006] Finished load of: file:///Users/giovannialtrui/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0X97XA8A-5304-406X-XPDD-17626B4A14D6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/694332C6-1FB7-46DE-XFBX-7A3A12FFD5F3/The%20Stranger.app/www/index.html
2020-09-18 16:22:36.826859+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:36.851983+0200 The Stranger[19593:446006] error JSON.stringify()ing argument: TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.
2020-09-18 16:22:36.852151+0200 The Stranger[19593:446006] error JSON.stringify()ing argument: TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.
2020-09-18 16:22:43.270954+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:43.336760+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:22:43.354899+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:23:01.264301+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2020-09-18 16:23:01.347071+0200 The Stranger[19593:446272] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
```

Comment: Did you get a solution for this issue?

Comment: hi @JobinsJohn 
no...and nobody seems to help us

Comment: Check if there is any link in your index.html which is not returning data or content. Check all the js files included or being called in the index page. I was able to solve it by removing one of the inclusions which returned 404.

Comment: hi @JobinsJohn, 
the problem is I can't figure out what.
you can figure it out based on the index you see below and the previous post containing the errors:
Also I don't understand why the screen emits continuous flashes which then stop even if no image is displayed.

<meta charset="UTF-8">
  
        <link rel="icon" href="icon/icon.png" type="image/png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon/icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/gamefont.css">

Comment: After XCode update and Ionic cordova build ios --prod same problem here.